# Embed Google Analytics Map View using API

Tags: api, google-analytics, embed, google-analytics-api, polymer-elements

I'm trying to display the "Active Users on Site" count and their location on a US map. We have Google Analytics installed and our dashboard is picking up live data. I'm trying to insert this onto a webpage hosted on our server to display on various screens inside our company building.

I've read through [this documentation](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/) but I'm not seeing anything displayed on my webpage where this code is placed. It is simply a white screen, no errors in console.

Looking at this part, [Polymer Elements](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/polymer-elements/), it looks like it is possible and I've inserted the HTML elements to do so. Yet, nothing.

Here is my code below with the CLIENT ID removed for privacy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Embed API Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Step 1: Create the containing elements. -->

<section id="auth-button"></section>
<section id="view-selector"></section>
<section id="timeline"></section>

    <google-analytics-chart
      type="area"
      metrics="ga:sessions"
      dimensions="ga:date"
      startDate="30daysAgo"
      endDate="yesterday">
    </google-analytics-chart>

<!-- Step 2: Load the library. -->

<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  // Step 3: Authorize the user.


  var CLIENT_ID = 'REMOVED-FOR-PRIVACY';

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
  });

  // Step 4: Create the view selector.

  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector'
  });

  // Step 5: Create the timeline chart.

  var chart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:country',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'GEO',
      container: 'timeline',
      options: {
        region: '1', // Western Europe
        displayMode: 'markers'
      }
    }
  });

  // Step 6: Hook up the components to work together.

  gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
    viewSelector.execute();
  });

  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    var newIds = {
      query: {
        ids: ids
      }
    }
    chart.set(newIds).execute();
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ultimately, I'd like to embed and display the two elements below:

[image: Google Analytics Dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those polymer elements are for viewing data on GA accounts that the visitor has access to, not for you to display results to users about your site.

I would suggest that you use Google Data Studio and create a report. Then embed the report on your webpage. https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7450249?hl=en

Also note that this won't be live data, you can use the [real time api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) for that, but I'm not aware of any out of the box solutions to display the data.

Comment: Honestly the webpage will only be accessible by internal users and displayed on one TV in our office. We need the live reports if possible.

Comment: Using the ga analytics api won’t get you real time data either. It will be at least a few hours behind.

Comment: Okay, honestly that's not too bad as long as it's within a few hours. So should my plan of attack be to use the Google Data Studio to first create the report, then use something to eventually refresh the report so it updates? Sorry, just trying to make sure I'm think about this correctly, or will it update automatically?

Comment: When you embed the report, can you just set the page to refresh every hour for example?

Comment: That's what I have it set to do now, thank you for your suggestions!